# How to exclude test folder from component scan annotation in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext, component-scan

```
App
|-src
    |-com
        |-xx
            |-model
                |-IclassA.java
                    |-impl
                        |-ClassA.java
|-test
    |-com
        |-xx
            |-model
                |-Conf.java
                    |-impl
                        |-ClassATest.java
```

i have an XML file for the productions and a java conf file for the tests

In the Conf.java i have a bean deceleration for ClassA and i'm using it in the test as

```
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = Conf.class)
```

In the xml i have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.*" />` , the problem is that this scan is scanning the test folder as well and recognize like i have 2 deceleration of ClassA, one in the XML and one in the Conf.java file.

Is there away to exclude the scan for the test folder?

Comment: I'm wondering if the the underlying issue might be that your test classes are on your runtime class path.

Comment: I created the project with intellij as spring .. did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `context:exclude-filter`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.*">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="**.*Test"/>
 </context:component-scan>
```

Comment: are you sure regarding the **.*Test ? i'm getting an error for that